# Is is possible to get elements by specifying a range of attribute values using QuerySelectoAll

Tags: javascript

I have a grid in which I have sequential items each having been assigned with an `index = n`. When an item in this grid is clicked I determine the first element (start) followed by highlighting it, and then the last element (end) given that the grid would only allow for selecting an initial point and a final point (two points only). At this point I would like to determine the distance between the two point using the `index = n` attribute. I also require to highlight all the items in between. For that purpose I may need to determine all the child elements whose index value fall in that range and the `querySelectorAll` method has come to mind.

Now the question is, is there any way I could acquire all those elements based on a range of attribute values?

Comment: In general: select all elements and filter them by index

Comment: @Justinas: This is an interesting post. Thank you

Comment: Do you have other elements in the div that contains those numbered elements?

Comment: @SalmanA: No, as I said those are sequential items

Comment: This question has been closed but you could use `:nth-child` to select element with index between say 3 and 5.

Comment: @SalmanA: That is a CSS solution.